# Ctrl+Enter keyboard shortcut stops working intermittently in RStudio

Tags: r, rstudio, r-markdown

I'm using Mac OS Sierra (10.12.6) and RStudio Version 1.1.463.  I usually do my work interactively through an RMarkDown notebook where I selectively run code-chunks by highlighting them and pressing "Control+Enter" to run that code selection.

Sometimes Control+Enter does not do anything, and I cannot identify the circumstances that cause this glitch to happen. Sometimes this occurs when I have an R Markdown code chunk that is not closed with the three backquotes (```) that are necessary to complete the code chunk.  Apparently code will not run if it is not enclosed with the correct syntax for an R markdown code chunk.

However, I often get the glitch even when I have a well-formed code chunk.  Does anybody else have this problem?  What are some common causes?